# setxkbmap for macbook pro (US)

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I recently installed awesome on my ubuntu oneiric, a nice window manager. This doesn't seem to inherit the keyboard settings that were set in the Unity settings.

Now, the problem is, I can't seem to find the correct keyboard layout to set (using setxkbmap). The control panel in Unity just states "US", bet with

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

some keys don't work correctly on my macbook pro 8,2. Does anyone here know the correct settings?

Comment: Just guessing: `setxkbmap -layout us -variant mac`, or `setxkbmap -model macbook78` (or `macbook79` for the international keyboard)

Comment: none of the above work. The problem is that the `~` key should be left to the `z` key, but instead it is left to the `1` key.

Comment: ok I just edited the files, and it works using `setxkbmap`. How do I make this permanent (e.g. call `setxkbmap` on ubuntu, using awesome wm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point was that the `mac us` keymap (`setxkbmap -layout us -variant mac`) had some keys at the wrong spot.

I edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, where it seemed that the `TLDE` and `LSGT` key are switched in the `mac` section. Loading `setxkbmap -layout us -variant mac` does the trick now.